# Does Scripture actually call Jesus' disciples " believers?"

Tags: terminology

I'm currently working on a Bible Study Titled "from believer to follower" Closer to God through his Word. I actually can't find one Instance where us saints/disciples, etc. are called believers! I realize the word is in some translations of the Scriptures, BUT when I look up the original word, it's actually just "brethren." Seems the translators themselves chose to use the word believer(s). Is there anywhere in Scripture where the original form and language refers to us as believers?
Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I think some people would think it is bad form to cook up a title first and then dig into the Bible to justify it.  Rather than imposing a topic on the Bible, shouldn't the topic come out of the Bible?

Comment: @B.Goddard  The OP has not 'cooked up a title'. The term 'believers' has been in common usage 
  for the past century. [See Ngram 1922-2022](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=believers%2Cfaithful%2CChristians&year_start=1922&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) The OP has done exactly what you suggest, they have enquired as to the validity of an English term in common usage, and whether it is warranted.

Comment: @NigelJ  I don't think so.  To do proper exegesis, one would find the concept of "from believer to follower" in the Bible and go from there.  In which case, he wouldn't have this question.

Answer (score 6):

[Strong (4103)](https://biblehub.com/greek/4103.htm) gives 67 occurrences in the New Testament of the word πιστός, *pistos*, which is mostly translated 'faithful'.

The relationship of the Greek word πιστός, *pistos*, to the Greek word *πίστις*, *pistis* (usually translated 'faith' or 'faithfulness') [see Strong 4102](https://biblehub.com/greek/4102.htm) is the same as the relationship of the English word 'faithful' to the English words 'faith' or 'faithfulness' ; that is to say adjective to noun.

The word 'believer' is somewhat weaker than the word 'faithful' in English as the word 'believer' does not carry the same connotations of behaviour and character as does the word 'faithful', see below for the Oxford English Dictionary definitions. 'Believer' denotes an adherence, or a membership, rather than being a description of characteristics.

This meaning is that which is now the usage of the word in common parlance, it should be noted.

Also, using an adjectival description,'faithful', is more true to the original Greek than is translating πιστός, *pistos*, (an adjective) with the word 'believer' (a noun).

---

The word 'believer' does not occur at all in the KJV (see Young's Analytical Concordance) but the word 'believe' occurs multiple times, translating πιστεύω, *pisteuw* [See Strong 4100](https://biblehub.com/greek/4100.htm)

---

> Theology. A person who believes in a god or the doctrines of a religion; esp. a Christian. Sometimes: spec. a member, esp. a fellow member, of a particular Christian group.

[Oxford English Dictionary - 'believer' 1.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/17378?redirectedFrom=believer#eid)

> b. Of friendship, love, etc.: loyal, constant, steadfast.

[Oxford English Dictionary - 'faithful' A/1/a](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67763?redirectedFrom=faithful#eid)

Comment: FWIW Acts 2:44 uses the word πιστεύοντες which I think is basically “those believing” or “believers”.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thanks so much! This is all very helpful. I'm surprised how believing or being a believer is the main term used in the church world. There are definitely much stronger and Biblical terms we can use :)

Comment: @bob πιστεύοντες is the [present participle active](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/acts/2-44.htm) . Acts 2:44 _does_ contain the article and therefore 'those having believed' would be a correct translation. (I made a mistake, previously, and missed seeing the article.) It is a further step in translation, however, to move from a verbal to a nounal expression. _All of those, now, having believed ... etc_ would be the literal, and faithful, rendering, in my own view.

Comment: I agree—I prefer a more literal rendering there to just “believers” though I’d be ok with it too.